# Angular not found until after it's needed?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angularjs-routing

We're trying to get Angular set up for a fairly simple project using Gulp, but we're somehow failing at the first hurdle. Here's what we have set up, more or less:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="testModule">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Module</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- inject:bundle:js -->
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->
  </body>
</html>
```

bundle.js:

```
// A bunch of stuff inserted by Gulp.
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

var angular;

(function () {

    angular.module('testModule', ['ngRoute']);

    angular.module('testModule').config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/foo', {
            template: '<p>Hi.</p>'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/foo'
        });
    }]);
})();

},{}]},{},[1])


//# sourceMappingURL=bundle.js.map
```

This seems simple enough to be foolproof, yet here are the errors we're getting:

angular-route.js:24: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined`
bundle.js:8: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined`
angular.js:4458: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module testModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'testModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

It almost seems like the browser doesn't know angular exists when processing `angular-route` and `bundle`, and only figures it out later. How can we get the browser to detect the presence of angular earlier so everything works?

Comment: you need to include the `angular.js` script before the `angular-route.js` script

Comment: @rob: we tried this and it eliminated the error from `angular-route.js`, but it still processes the `bundle.js` script before `angular.js` even though it's imported later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to initialize the variable `angular` manually.

Here's a plunker, and you'll note we're brought right to the view for `/foo`: http://plnkr.co/edit/dxo3ZUJIWLeFw9HXF80w?p=info

```
  angular.module('testModule', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/foo', {
            template: '<p>Hi.</p>'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/foo'
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: It turns out that initializing 'angular' manually was causing the problem. It worked fine in previous projects, so I'm not sure why it was breaking here. Working great now, though. Thanks!

Comment: Good find, looks like the double instantiation had no effect. Updated my answer to reflect this, ya learn something new everyday!